# Unexpected 'delete' return value

Tags: javascript

I have the following snippet in which the last 'delete' usage is returning an unexpected value.

```js
function Shape() {
  this.a = 10;
}
Shape.prototype.a = 20;
var s = new Shape();
console.log(s.a); // 10
delete s.a; //true
console.log(s.a) // 20
delete s.a; //true
console.log(s.a); // 20
```

Even though the final 'delete s.a' returns true, the value of 's.a' still returns 20.

If we cannot delete objects on prototype through a reference from an object (in this case 's'), why does the delete keyword return true?

Secondly,

`delete Shape.prototype.a; // true`

gives out true and the property is indeed deleted from Shape.prototype. But is there any way to delete 'Shape.prototype.a' through the object reference 's'?

Comment: What do you mean `delete` returns `true`? `delete` is a statement, not an expression.

Comment: You can check the return value of 'delete' in the console. It returns 'true' after evaluation of statement if the item is deleted.

Comment: Please check the 'delete' usage before downvoting the question. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Comment: Sorry. I was wrong. `delete` is an operator not a statement. PS: Why do you think it was me who downvoted the question? It could be anyone. PPS: It was not me who downvoted the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `delete` keyword's return value does **not** indicate whether the delete operation did in fact remove a field. From the [MDN article about delete keyword](http://Return%20value%20%20Throws%20in%20strict%20mode%20if%20the%20property%20is%20an%20own%20non-configurable%20property%20(returns%20false%20in%20non-strict).%20Returns%20true%20in%20all%20other%20cases.):

> **Return value**
>
> Throws in strict mode if the property is an own non-configurable
>   property (returns false in non-strict). Returns true in all other
>   cases.

In your case `s.a` is not an own property, so `delete` will always return `true`. It does not matter if the property is found in the prototype chain or not. For example:

```
delete {}.xyz; // also returns `true`.
```

You should not mutate prototypes, as it will break all the optimizations the JavaScript engine does for you to improve performance. However, if you really want to, you can use this function:

```
function deepDelete(o,key) {
  while (o) {
    delete o[key];
    o = Object.getPrototypeOf(o);
  }
}
```

Example:

```
function S(){}
S.prototype.a = 8;
var s = new S();
s.a = 9;
console.log(s.a); // 9
delete s.a;
console.log(s.a); // 8
deepDelete(s, 'a');
console.log(s.a); // undefined
```

Comment: I'm wondering what `deepDelete` does for host objects (say, DOM elements in old IE)... ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Well, to be honest, I have no idea (who has? :) )

Comment: My best guess is that it crashes the code. Either with a null pointer exception or with something weird and uncatchable.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Shape() {
  //this.a = 10;
}

Shape.prototype.a = 20;
var s = new Shape();

console.log(s.a);

delete Shape.prototype.a;
console.log(s.a);
```

And as quoted by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) and also mentioned in the answer by hege_hegedus,

> **Return value**
>
> Throws in strict mode if the property is an own non-configurable
>   property (returns false in non-strict). Returns true in all other
>   cases.

Bottom line is delete is an operator and not a method and it just removes a property from an Object, `a` is the property of `Shape.prototype` and not of the object of the class `Shape`, so you need to delete that instead of `delete s.a`

Answer (score 0):

the 'delete' method can only delete the own property of the object and not the prototype's property. when you delete a property which don't exsit in the object, it will return ture; however the situation below will return false:

```js
delete Object.prototype; //renturn false; property can't set
var x=1;
delete this.x; //return flase;can not delete a global var
function f(){}
delete this.f; //return false; can not delete a global function
```

Comment: you can also us 'in' operator、hasOwnProperty() or propertyIsEnumerable() to test if the property belong to an object. and there is still a easy way to do that: o.x!==undefined;